# Using checkboxes in a PHP form with MySQL and multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a PHP form (new.php) to update 2 MySQL tables and retrieve information from a 3rd. The reason I need to use 3 tables is so that the information stored can be searched via another form (search.php) and, also, so that the information can be easily edited (edit.php).

New.php makes use of 4 text entry fields and, currently, 3 checkboxes (though this number will increase once I've gotten these 3 to work). The checkboxes act as "tags" that are used to describe articles that are entered into the database. So, a single entry in the database contains the following information:

Article Title, Article Organization, Access Date, Article URL, and Article Tag(s) (and there is also an `id` column for this table.

The title, organization, date, and url are all stored in a table named `articles`.

The tags are all stored in a table named `tags` (there are 85 of them). This table has 2 columns: `id` and `tag_contents`.

The 3rd table is a relation table (or maybe it's called an "intersection table"?) called `articles_tags` with 2 columns: article_id and tag_id.

What new.php currently does is add the title, organization, date, and url to the `articles` table and, then, uses `mysql_insert_id()` to get the ID of that entry.

But, after that, I can't figure out what I need to do with my checkboxes.

I have 3 checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="science" id="articletags_0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="geology" id="articletags_1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="astronomy" id="articletags_2" />
```

I need to somehow use those checkboxes to make a relation with the article. So, for example, after inserting an article about rocks the form would look like:

```
Article Title: Great new rocks!
Article Organization: US Geology Assoc.
Access Date: 09/20/2012
Article URL: www.rocks.com

Science [X]    Geology [X]    Astronomy [ ] (note that the X marks a checked checkbox)
```

And, the database tables would look like this:

```
(table: articles) id | articletitle     | articleorganization | articledate | articleurl
                  13 | great new rocks! | US geology assoc.   | 9/20/2012   | www.rocks.com


(table: tags)     id | tag_contents
                   5 | geology
                   9 | science

(table: articles_tags)   article_id  | tag_id
                            13       |   5
                            13       |   9
```

Note that the `tags` table doesn't change, it only stores the available tags and allows them to be referenced by the table `articles_tags`.

I can not figure this situation out and I've been hacking at it for a week now. For reference, the code for new.php is added below:

```
    <?php 
 }

 // connect to the database
 include('settings.php');

 if(count($articletags) > 0)
{
 $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
}
 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 { 
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
 $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
 $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
 $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));

 // check to make sure both fields are entered
 if ($articletitle == '' || $articleorganization == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 // if either field is blank, display the form again
 renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
      articleorganization='$articleorganization',
      articledate='$articledate',
      articleurl='$articleurl' ")

 or die(mysql_error()); 

 $article_id = mysql_insert_id();

 foreach( $POST_['articletags'] as $newtag )
{
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES ($article_id, $newtag)');
}

 // once saved, redirect to success page
 header("Location:addsuccess.php");  
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
 {
 renderForm('','','','','');
 }
?>
```

Comment: Are you using the checkboxes as input for a new article, or output for viewing an existing article?

Comment: @Matt The checkboxes are input for a new article and, hopefully, will be editable later given an existing article. (As in, edit.php will be a similar form, but with the text fields filled in, and with the checkboxes already checked though the user can uncheck them, or check other ones)

Comment: If your question is really "How do I process input from checkboxes in php?", try this http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="5" id="articletags_0" />Science
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="9" id="articletags_1" />Geology
```

then in php

```
foreach( $POST_['articletags'] as $newtag )
{
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO articles_tags(article_id,tagID) VALUES( $idFromArticleInsert, $newtag )')
}
```